# SSRS 2008 R2 - DynamicWidth does not work

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a report in SSRS with chart in which I have set the following DynamicWidth expression:

```
=Iif(UCase(Globals!RenderFormat.Name) = "PDF", "26", "10") & " cm"
```

However, when exporting to PDF from report manager the chart size does not change.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I placed a textbox to look up `Globals!RenderFormat.Name` and it turns out it is giving `#ERROR`, and is marked as 'unrecognized identifier' in expression editor. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Please try this expression: =IIf(UCase(Globals!RenderFormat.Name) = "PDF", "26 CM", "10 CM")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution - turns out the server is in vanilla 2008 version, not R2.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Try this

```
=IIF(UCASE(Globals!RenderFormat.Name)="PDF","26","10 ")+"CM"
```

**UPDATE**

---

I Have tested on SSRS 2008 it works fine

Comment: This expression fails as well.

Comment: I am using it in chart`s DynamicWidth and DynamicHeight expression. There is no error, the report deploys but does not scale the chart when exported to PDF.

Comment: Try using the `in` instead of `CM` And let me know the results

Comment: That's not the root cause, it is Globals!RenderFormat.Name throwing #Error.

Comment: Simple test the Globals!RenderFormat.Name with the other temp report to know if it's problmetic in all reports or only your report

Comment: Does report able to acess any of the `globals` values